# SharePoint 2010 multi-valued lookup appears empty to some users

Tags: sharepoint

I have a lookup field in one of my document libraries, that pulls countries list from an external list. This field allows multiple values.
For some reason, two of our users cannot see the list of countries in the form but others do see it. They tried it with different browsers but no help, we did a test in a different library and this time they could see it, so it has to be something in the original list's or field settings. what is it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I found another thread for the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173932/sharepoint-custom-list-form-display-with-multi-value-lookup-field
I am going to try it now because I have exactly the same problem. Good luck!